# Is my REST API call format a valid one

Tags: api, rest, servlets

I am new to the area of Rest API. And I am working on a third party web application, that provides an API to execute some of its actions. And one of these actions is adding a new Server. So I specified the following:-

```
http://win-spdev:8400/servlets/AssetServlet?Operation='AddAsset'&assetName='serverfromapi'&assetType='server'&model='Unkown Server'&Product Name='Unknown%20Server'&siteName='s1'&accountName='customer3'&username='admin'&password='admin'&DOMAIN_NAME='win-spdev:8400'&logonDomainName=
```

But I will get “#”, when I wrote the above insdie my browser. So basically is my API call format a valid one ?

Answer (score 1):

An URL like

```
http://win-spdev:8400/servlets/AssetServlet?Operation='AddAsset'&assetName='serverfromapi'&assetType='assetType'&model='Unkown Server'&Product Name='Unknown%20Server'&siteName='s1'&accountName='customer3'&username='admin'&password='admin'&DOMAIN_NAME='win-spdev:8400'&logonDomainName=
```

is not RESTful. This is RPC over HTTP.

If you want to add a `Server` resource in a RESTful way, an API like this would be possible:

**The URL**

```
POST /path/to/servers
```

**The body**

```
{
  'assetName':'serverfromapi',
  'assetType':'assetType',
  'model':'Unkown Server',
  'Product Name':'Unknown Server',
  'siteName':'s1',
  'accountName':'customer3',
  'username':'admin',
  'password':'admin',
  'DOMAIN_NAME':'win-spdev:8400',
  'logonDomainName':''
}
```